# Android SipAudioCall sendDtmf

Tags: android, call, sip, rtp, dtmf

I have a working application that allows two devices to talk about a sip server. I am now trying to integrate dtmf tones so one user can press a button and a tone will be received on the other end.

According to the docs I can just use `currentCall.sendDtmf(5);` for example but it doesn't do anything? After doing some research I can see there are different ways to send the DTMF tone: RTP, In band generation and SIP INFO. When using CSipSimple the 'In band generation' option works, how can I force mine to do the same?

Comment: which `sipstack` you are using?

Comment: I am using the inbuilt library, http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Counterpath X-Lite V4.9.8 to help develop an Android OS SIP app using the native SIP library.  The X-Lite Softphone/Preferences/Calls should be set to "Send via RFC 2833".

Once you have an active SIP call with bi-directional audio, and you use yourcall.sendDtmf(5) during that call, you can hear the DTMF tones via the X-Lite app, with the tones lasting a variable amount of time.  Trying to learn how to control the duration of the DTMF output.

Comment: Also this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515604/tonegenerator-crashes-in-android-6-0/45179525#45179525